# Why are evicted dependencies not excluded in sbt publish task

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, classpath

Should evicted dependencies be automatically excluded? They are, after all, evicted...

In unit-tests they seem to be excluded from the classpath but when publishing they are not excluded in the pom.

When loading my library in a REPL it happily loads those 'which should be evicted' to the classpath, resulting in conflicts (e.g. NoClassDefFoundError).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a bug, so have raised https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4662 for SBT maintainers to respond